# git: master and develop are different but merge tell me already updated

Tags: git

```
git checkout develop

> Switched to branch "develop"

git merge --no-ff master

> Already up-to-date

git checkout master

> Switched to branch "master"

git merge --no-ff develop

> Already up-to-date
```

But ...

```
git diff --shortstat master develop

> 725 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 297085 deletions (-)
```

What's happening ?
How fully resync the 2 branches ?

Comment: What does the log look like for the 2 branches? What's the output of `git log --oneline --graph -5 master` and `git log --oneline --graph -5 develop`?

Comment: To see the situation in one command, try `git log --oneline --graph master...develop` (note the three-dot syntax).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing all files from index:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Then

```
git add *
git commit -m "title_commit"
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

Comment: I've got the same results